# SQL Oracle, select distinct unordered couples

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

My table has two columns which identify two distinct individuals in relation with each other; however, any couple may appear more than once with the individuals switched between the columns (e.g. A sells 100 to B, and B sells 150 to A):

```
id1  id2  value
 A    B    100
 C    B    110
 B    A    150
```

I need to obtain a table where each couple appears only once, i.e. I need to find distinct unordered couples, and sum the value from all the corresponding rows:

```
id1  id2  value
 A    B    250
 C    B    110
```

How can I get an "index" for the distinct unordered couples? How should I approach this task?

---

EDIT: Extra issue. Say I also have an attribute for each Id, e.g. the country:

```
id1  id2  country1 country2 value
 A    B         IT      FR   100
 C    B         US      FR   110
 B    A         FR      IT   150
```

I obviously can use a join to get them back in the results table, in a second step. However, is there a way to keep them in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(id1, id2) as id1, greatest(id1, id2) as id2, sum(value)
from t
group by least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2)
```

Comment: Great. I have to add something to the original question, I have some attributes for id1 and id2 (say country1 and country2). I can get them back with a join afterwards, but is there a more elegant way to keep them in the table? (Maybe I need to make a second question).

Comment: @Giuseppe . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  Also, be sure to explain what happens when the attributes are different on different rows that would otherwise match.